# folder sharing using apache 2.2.26

Tags: apache

I am new to apache. I am using apache 2.2.26 in mac.

I want to give link to user for a folder, using which he will download files from that folder. i created a conf file under /Private/etc/apache2/other/ with following settings

```
Alias /outputfiles/ /Users/XXXX/sharing

<Directory "/Users/XXXX/sharing">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

when i issued "localhost/outputfiles/" in browser, i got 403 Forbidden message.

and error_log contains following at end of file.

```
[Thu Oct 30 10:20:22 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8za configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 30 10:20:26 2014] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/XXXX/sharingindex.html
```

ls -la for /Users/XXXX/sharing 
commmand gives following output

```
    total 128
    drwxr-xr-x   7 755           110063367    238 Oct 29 16:07 .
    drwxr-xr-x+ 43 XXXX  110063367   1462 Oct 30 10:18 ..
    -rw-r--r--@  1 755           110063367   6148 Oct 30 10:17 .DS_Store
    -rw-r--r--@  1 755           110063367  37441 Sep  1 12:28 Trade.txt
    -rw-r--r--   1 755           110063367   3727 Sep  1 11:44 census.txt
    -rw-r--r--   1 755           110063367   4683 Sep 19 15:23 script.sh
    -rw-r--r--   1 755           110063367     22 Sep 23 15:27 testing.sql
```

Can you please guide me in this.

Comment: Please provide the output of `ls -la /Users/XXXX/sharing`, or at least the lines for `.`, `..` and `sharingindex.html`.

Comment: i have added ls -la output at end of my post

Comment: Is that `sharingindex.html` in the error message a typo? I'm easily confused, my rule of thumb with `Alias` is to have both sides end in `/` or neither, to avoid slashes appearing and disappearing.